# Get DHCP IP address of Raspbery Pi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, raspberry-pi3

I have a .NetCore c# app.
I am using it in a Raspberry Pi device running Raspbian.

I am trying to get my assigned DHCP IP address.

I have tried many things.

They all return 127.0.0.1.

This is using web sockets. The server is written in c# and client is written in JS.

Any ideas apart from the usual examples out there?

Latest attempts:

```
  public void GetIPAddress()
  {
     List<string> IpAddress = new List<string>();
        var Hosts = System.Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetHostNames().ToList();
        foreach (var Host in Hosts)
        {
            string IP = Host.DisplayName;
            IpAddress.Add(IP);
        }
        IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(IpAddress.Last());
        Console.WriteLine(address);
    }
```

Tells me that "The type or namespace name 'Networking' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

```
    public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        var localIP = "";
        try
        {
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    localIP = ip.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(localIP);
                    //break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( e );
            Environment.Exit( 0 );
        }
        return localIP;
    }
```

Returns 127.0.0.1

**should also point out that using 127.0.0.1 as the web socket connection does not work for some reason**

Comment: _" (as this is a server socket app) "_ Do you really need to bind only to one interface? (your rpi has probably only one interface)   You could use: `IpAddress.Any` for a serversocket bind

Comment: @J.vanLangen hi, thanks for looking at this.  I am actually using web sockets.  The client is in JS and the server is on the same device in c#

Comment: should also point out that using 127.0.0.1 as the socket connection does not work for some reason

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.dhcpserveraddresses?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_NetworkInformation_IPInterfaceProperties_DhcpServerAddresses

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto That only returned 127.0.0.1 when in the Raspberry Pi. i already found the answer which should be blow :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than rely on .Net Core libraries/framework I instead googled linux commands to get the ip address as I know it does this.
If I open a Terminal window on the Pi and type in:

```
hostname -I
```

it will return the ip address.

So, my next step was to run this linux command from within C#.

For this I can use the process class and redirct the output:

```
//instantiate a new process with c# app
var proc = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "hostname",  //my linux command i want to execute
            Arguments = "-I",  //the argument to return ip address
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,  //redirect output to my code here
            CreateNoWindow = true  /do not show a window
        }
    };

    proc.Start();  //start the process
    while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)  //wait until entire stream from output read in
    {
        Console.WriteLine( proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine());  //this contains the ip output                    
    }
```

Comment: is it not obvious?

Comment: happy?    this was my own question I answered just wanted to share what I found